# UWP XAML-Gridview displays first item differently

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a UWP app in windows 10. I have a page inside a frame calling a gridview:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind PassedMiniList}"
          IsItemClickEnabled="True">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Miniature">
            <local:MiniListControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

            </local:MiniListControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Each item is based on the following UserControl, sorry about the length:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock"
           x:Key="TextBoxData">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                Value="Right" />
        <Setter Property="Padding"
                Value="10,0,0,0" />
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping"
                Value="Wrap" />

    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Image"
           x:Key="MiniImage">
        <Setter Property="MaxWidth"
                Value="200" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="StackPanel"
           x:Key="MiniOuterStackPanel">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                Value="3" />
        <Setter Property="Margin"
                Value="5,5,5,5" />
        <Setter Property="Padding"
                Value="5,5,5,5" />

    </Style>       

</UserControl.Resources>
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
            Name="OuterStackPanel"                
            Style="{StaticResource MiniOuterStackPanel}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="NarrowLayout">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MiniImage.Width"
                            Value="100" />
                    <Setter Target="MiniImage.Height"
                            Value="100" />                       
                    <!--Works in theory, but because of width of set name, doesnt change overall size of SP-->
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="WideLayout">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="600" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MiniImage.Width"
                            Value="200" />
                    <Setter Target="MiniImage.Height"
                            Value="200" />

                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Image Name="MiniImage"
           Source="{x:Bind Miniature.Image}"/>
    <Grid MinHeight="150" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />                
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Name:" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="{x:Bind Miniature.Name}"
                   Style="{StaticResource TextBoxData}" />
        <TextBlock Text="Quantity:" 
                   Grid.Row="1"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   Text="{x:Bind Miniature.Quantity}"
                   Style="{StaticResource TextBoxData}" />
        <TextBlock Text="Manufacturer:"
                   Grid.Row="2"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                   Grid.Row="2"
                   Text="{x:Bind Miniature.Manufacturer}"
                   Style="{StaticResource TextBoxData}" />
        <TextBlock Text="Set:"
                   Grid.Row="3"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                   Grid.Row="3"
                   Text="{x:Bind Miniature.Set}"
                   Style="{StaticResource TextBoxData}" />
        <TextBlock Text="Location:"
                   Grid.Row="4" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                   Grid.Row="4"
                   Text="{x:Bind Miniature.Location}"
                   Style="{StaticResource TextBoxData}" />
    </Grid>  
</StackPanel>
```

Eventually I will be adding more to the visualstatemanager to adjust the look but for now the problem I have you can see in the following link: https://ibb.co/iUcS45

Essentially, the first item is either treated differently than the rest, or some the grid is using the first item as some sort of max width determiner and everything else is getting squeezed down. You can see the selected item shows the actual boundary of the object might actually be the same as the first item but is squeezed down. Now, for a variety of reasons, I don't want to force the items to a specific size. As you can see, the visual state manager is adjusting the image size based on the total width, and I would like the rest of the item to minimum amount of space alloted. This is what I think the items after the first are doing, and this is the sort of look i'm going for.
I did find this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592428/gridview-displays-first-element-different-than-all-others-xaml-win8-1-winrt) but it does not completely help because it changes the functionality of the gridview to where, rather than shuffling the items around, you must use the scrollviewer, and of course this forces a specific width.

Is there something I'm missing? I'm new to UWP somewhat but don't recall hearing about this in tutorials etc.

Edit-It might be worth noting I had a version if this working where I used a series of stack panels instead of the grid I put below the image and that seemed to work fine, except it looked like trash because I couldnt get it to right justify. That might be a better option but could also be a separate SO question in its own right...

Comment: How big is the first item's image (compared to the rest)? I don't see you are styling the Image properly because you didn't set the Style.

Comment: Check the link https://ibb.co/iUcS45 The image style was created to troubleshoot and didnt actually have any effect on the issue I'm having. Also, I dont want to fix this fixed width in style because I cant use the visualstatemanager to change styles.